# replace text in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to update some data from mysql data:

Table name: wp_postmeta

```
|  meta_id  |  post_id  |  meta_key  |           meta_value         |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------------------------+
|     1     |     1     |  _meta_url | http://domain.com/image1.jpg |
```

how I can replace domain base for all `meta_keys _meta_url` to another domain like: `http://newdomain.com/path/image1.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) string function.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value=replace(meta_value, 'domain.com/', 'newdomain.com/path/')
WHERE meta_key='_meta_url';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace()` function:

```
  update wp_postmeta 
  set meta_value=replace(meta_value,"domain.com/","newdomain.com/path/")
  WHERE meta_key='_meta_url'
```

Here is syntax : `replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]')`